# How many different pairs of dominoes with a unique combination of four numbers could be combined to yield $20$?

Tags: combinatorics

> A student has an unlimited supply of dominoes, which are each labeled with two numbers. Each numbers is a member of the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$ The student picks two dominoes, multiplies the numbers on each domino, then adds the two products. So, for instance, the two dominoes labeled $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ would be combined to yield $(a \times b) + (c \times d).$ How many different pairs of dominoes with a unique combination of four numbers could be combined to yield $20$? (Note that $(2,4)$ and $(2,6)$ should be included, but is considered the same pair as $(4,2)$ and $(2,6)$ which is the same pair as $(2,6)$ and $(4,2),$ etc.)

I brute forced this question and got $20$ pairs. Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Double check your brute force; there are 14 pairs after applying the 'unique combination' restriction.

Comment: Does this need to be brute forced and also how did you get $14$?

Comment: I haven't established an elegant solution yet. 1. Determine the possible products for one domino (19). 2. Determine the product pairs that sum to twenty, and how many unique pairs there are: 20+0 (7), 18+2 (1), 16+4(2), 15+5 (1), 12+8 (2), & 10+10 (1). I utilized excel to slog through.

Comment: I think that is the elegant solution what you are describing. It shouldn't be too hard then to count those up.

Answer (score 2):

If the objective is 20, summed from two products that are formed by the unique arrangement of two dominoes, first determine what the possible products are.

The dominos, as detailed, feature two numbers from the set $(0,1,2,3,4,5,6).$ An additional restriction is that the pairings be unique, where (2,4) and (4,2) are interchangeable. So, the potential products, including the number of unique pairings that produce them, are:

$0 (7), 2 (1), 4 (2), 5 (1), 8 (1), 10 (1), 12 (2), 15 (1), 16 (1), 18 (1), \text{ and } 20 (1). $

Pruned from that list are the products that don't conductively aid in generating the objective sum: 3, 6, 9, 18, 24, 25, 30, and 36.

Of those products, the following unique pairings sum to 20.

$0_7 + 20_1 = 20,  7$
$2_1 + 18_1 = 20,  1$
$4_2 + 16_1 = 20,  2$
$5_1 + 15_1 = 20,  1$
$8_1 + 12_2 = 20,  2$
$10_1 + 10_1 = 20, 1$

Total number of pairings: $7+1+2+1+2+1=14$